# Make sibling height change depending on contenteditable(s) height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an example I cannot figure out,

I have a container(`outer`) that contains three children, what I want is the middle container(div) to be resized in height depending on how big the contenteditable are. They should all "fit" into the outer-div.

```
<div id="outer"> //container

  <div id="contenthead" contenteditable="true">head</div>       
  <div id="content"> I am content </div> <!-- I should shrink or grow depending on the content editable -->

  <div id="contentend" contenteditable="true">end</div>

</div>
```

I have tried using a `mutationobserver`, I have tried using `jquery ui` but even if they produce a solution they only work "so-so" sometimes not firing an event or loosing a pixel or two.

Anyone have any idea on how to do that?

I made an example: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/066pov55/1/) , it should explain it better of what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#contenthead,
#contentend {
  background: pink;
}
#content {
  width: inherit;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">

  <div id="contenthead" contenteditable="true">head</div>

  <div id="content">I am content</div>

  <div id="contentend" contenteditable="true">end</div>

</div>
```

Comment: without `min-height: 200px;` in `.content` doesn't exceed the height of container

Comment: Either way, this is the right answer as it fixes the height of the div depending on flex. Didnt know this existed! Thanks Paulie_D.

Comment: If you want the center portion to have a scroll if it has a lot of content there you can do that too - https://jsfiddle.net/066pov55/3/

Comment: I don't say is not right, but if you enter a lot of text in editable divs they excedd the heigh of the `#outer`. Sorry my English

Comment: I was wrong, without min-height that does not work neither, your scroll solution is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You must use `display` feature here

```css
.table {display:table;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:5px;}
.table-row {display:table-row;}
.table-cell {display:table-cell;padding:5px;border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">123</div>
  <div class="table-cell">456<Br />sdf</div>
  <div class="table-cell">879</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

i am sure this will help you.